# eTA Canada changed travel dates

Tags: canada, eta

I applied for and got approval for an eTA for a trip to Canada in about one week. In the process I indicated my travel dates as (if I remember correctly) that would somehow simplify things.

I may now need to leave a day later. Does that have any implications for my eTA? E.g., do I need to let them know about the changed dates? Do I need a new eTA altogether?

Comment: I can't find a reference to support this, so I'm commenting rather than answering, but I'm fairly certain that the answer is (1) no, there's no way to tell them, and (2) no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change in plans will not affect your eTA or its validity; it is recommended that you get your eTA before booking your flight.

> **[Do I need to apply for an eTA before I book my airline ticket?](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=1059&top=16)**
>   We recommend that you submit your eTA application before you buy your airline ticket. This way, if you encounter any difficulties when you apply, you can resolve any issues before you book your flight. In most cases, the eTA will be issued in minutes, which will not delay your flight booking. However, some requests may need more time to process.
>
> An [**Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA)**](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/eta/facts.html) is an entry requirement for visa-exempt foreign nationals travelling to Canada by air. An eTA is electronically linked to a traveller’s passport. It is valid for up to five years or until the passport expires, whichever comes first. If you get a new passport, you need to get a new eTA.